# Need help in structure pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

In c++ I have to make a program where I have to write a menu driven program to input, edit or display the name, id and cgpa of a student. The code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct student
{
    char name[20];
    int id;
    float cgpa;
};

void input(struct student *);
void display(struct student *);
void edit(struct student *);

int main()
{
    int ch;
    struct student a;

    while(ch!=4)
    {
        cout<<"1.input";
        cout<<"\n2.edit";
        cout<<"\n3.display";
        cout<<"\n4.exit";
        cout<<"\nenter your choice";
        cin>>ch;
        if(ch==1)
        {
            cout<<"enter name, id and cgpa of student\n";
            input(&a);
        }
        else if(ch==2)
        {
            cout<<"enter new name, id and cgpa  of the student\n";
            edit(&a);
        }
        else if(ch==3)
        {
            display(&a);
        }
        else if(ch==4)
        {
            ch=ch;
        }
        else{cout<<"wrong choice\n";}
    }

    return 0;
}

void input(struct student *s)
{
    cin>>s->name;
    cin.ignore(256,'\n');
    cin>>s->id;
    cin>>s->cgpa;
}

void edit(struct student *s)
{
    cin>>s->name;
    cin.ignore(256,'\n');
    cin>>s->id;
    cin>>s->cgpa;
}

void display(struct student *s)
{
    cout<<s->name<<"\n";
    cout<<s->id<<"\n";
    cout<<s->cgpa<<"\n";
}
```

But whenever I am inputting a name through cin.getline() function, it doesn't display a name on the screen. Instead a blank space is left there and id and cgpa are printed. Cin is working fine but cin does not take a space. What is wrong in the code that it is not printing the name while using cin.getline().

Comment: Can you do something about the indentation? Also could use a swtich statement. Why have the statement `ch=ch`/

Comment: @EdHeal Taken care of =P

Comment: @Ed Heal I wrote the code in a hurry, the main purpose is to find why is it not printing the name when I am using cin.getline() function in the input() function.

Comment: I don't see a getline in your code. So what is the part that is not working. Two tips for debugging this: (a) When in doubt, use parenthesis around complex expressions. (b) if something doesn't work, try to replace the offending expression by a constant. If that is output/processed correctly, your expression is propebly not what it should be. If the constant is also not output/processed correcly, you're probably not writing what you think you do. And (3) try to strip down your non working example to a minimal non working example. Usually you can then see what doesn't work. (4) Try a debugger.

Comment: "I wrote the code in a hurry". So you're spending the time you save writing the code in understanding how it is formatted? Presentation is important ...

Comment: You should use `std::string name` instead of `char name[20]`. `cin` doesn't interact with char arrays as you intend.

Comment: @AnkitArora - Get a better IDE

Comment: @Ed Heal I am currently using Code Blocks

Comment: @AnkitArora - Configure it.

Comment: @M.E.L. I would keep the presentation part in mind from the next time.  Yes, there isn't a getline() in my code. If I am using getline() instead of 'cin' in the input() function then the name is not getting printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `cin.ignore()` before calling `cin.getline()`

Or

make a dummy call `cin.getline()` to consume the trailing newline character from the `cin`